# Returning a variable to be used later in a GCD Sync operation - Swift 3

Tags: swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I'm having trouble finding a way to return a variable for use outside of the sync operation in a GCD Queue. I want something to basically run the following:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.yourapp.queue", qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated)

queue.sync(userLocation: CLLocation) -> CLLocation {
     let userLocation = mapView.myLocation

     return userLocation
}
```

I know this isn't how the syntax works, but any idea on how this would work?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `userLocation` outside of the `queue.sync` function.

e.g.

```
var userLocation: CLLocation?
queue.sync {
    userLocation = mapView.myLocation
}
```

Alternatively:

```
var myUserLocation: CLLocation?

func setLocation(userLocation: CLLocation) {
    myUserLocation = userLocation
}

queue.sync {
    self.setLocation(userLocation: mapView.myLocation)
}
```

If you would like a more detail answer though, I need to see more of your code. e.g. where is `mapView`? How do you want to use the `userLocation`. But I hope you get the gist of it.